# Symfony2 Get just 1 row of oneToMany Entity

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I have a user entity and a log entity. I have a OneToMany connection from User to Log.
In my Log Table are stored log entries according to users.

I output a User list:

**Controller:**

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
        ->findBy(array('isActive' => 1, 'isAdmin' => 0));
```

**TWIG**

```
{% for user in list_user %}
    {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to recieve ONE row of the log table, sorted by a field called "date" and return it in the for user loop like this:

```
{% for user in list_user %}
    {{ user.username }}
    {{ user.log.lastEntry
{% endfor %}
```

How do I do this?

**Entity User.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Log", mappedBy="user")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Log", mappedBy="editor")
 */
protected $log;
```

**Entity Log.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="log")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now in TWIG. But this isn't nice at all... I would prefere a solution inside of the controller and not in the VIEW.

```
{% for log in last_userlog|reverse if(log.user.Id == user.Id) %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        {{ log.logTitle }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your getter for accessing the `Log` Collection object is a `getLogMessages` method, and assuming you can access the log message with a `getMessage` method, the following should solve it:

```
{{ User.getLogMessages().last().getMessage() }}
```

The `last` method gives you access to the last element stored in the collection.

By the way, you should use the [`OrderBy` annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby), otherwise the order must be considered undefined. (Although, in reality, you will usually get the elements in the order they were inserted).

Comment: My "log message" field is called "log_title". So it should be {{ user.getLogLogTitle().last().getLogTitle() }} ??? With this I get this exception: Method "getLogLogTitle" for object "Proxies\__CG__\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User" does not exist in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Seotool/src/Seotool/MainBundle/Resources/views/Dashboard/taskManager.html.twig at line 29

Comment: Your `User` object must have a getter for the log entries. This getter returns an `ArrayCollection` or `DoctrineCollection` object. Both of them have various methods to get values of the collection, e.g. `getValues()` to get all, or first() to get the first, or `last()` to get the last element.

Comment: Ah ok, so I need to update my getLog method. Thank you, I will try :-)

Comment: Each class property that represents a OneToMany relation should set the property's value to an empty `ArrayCollection`. (`app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourFoobarBundle` does it for you, otherwise, if you already have a constructor on the class, insert `$this->myOneToManyCollection = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();`). The getters/setters don't need to contain anything special, they work like all others, too.